# Install OpenLayer with npm install. Python

Tags: python, node.js, openlayers-3, npm-install

I know it was discussed few times. But I have no ideas how to fix it.
I need install openlayer for my new project. I have downloaded Python and put it to C:\Python34.

I also checked global variables:

[image]

So when I run

```
npm install openlayers --save
```

I get:

[image]

I even tried to set PYTHON and PYTHONPATH variables manually using:

```
Run "npm config set python path\to\python\python.exe"
```

What it could be about ?

Comment: Did you try with Python2.7? If works fine after a fresh Python 2.7 installation. Btw, you'll also need a C++ compiler

Comment: After installing Visual C++ 2015, I get the error `MSB3491: Could  not write lines to file "Release\obj\validation\validation.tlog\validation.lastbuildstate". The specified pat h, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the di rectory name must be less than 248 characters. [D:\Source\......\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]` node paths are not windows friendly.

Answer (score 0):

On [OpenLayers Browserify](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/doc/tutorials/browserify.html) it states you should install with

`npm install --save-dev openlayers browserify watchify uglify-js`

That works without any issue on my Win8 PC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Python3.4 I should use Python2.7